# numpy memmap ignore EOF error

Tags: python, numpy

I am mapping a binary file to memory, which has a custom dtype. I do it like this:

```
np.memmap(filename=f, dtype=my_sample_dtype, mode='r')
```

Sometimes, the end of the binary file is chopped off, because the process that wrote it ended unexpectedly. In this case, numpy complains:

```
ValueError: Size of available data is not a multiple of the data-type size.
```

Now I could truncate the file on disk to make it a multiple of the data-type size, but I would like a solution that does not require touching the original file. Can I somehow tell numpy to just ignore the incomplete element at the end of the file?

Comment: Why don't you want to modify the file on disk to fix it?  Any chance of fixing the program that writes corrupted records?

Comment: Files are several GB each, and stored in a read-only location. The other program stops writing because of power failure, so it's not buggy. The software needs to be robust against such failure.

Comment: Do you know what the shape (at least `dims-1`) that the array should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right there in the [np.memmap documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html):

> **shape** : *tuple, optional*
>
> The desired shape of the array. If mode == 'r' and the number of remaining bytes after offset is not a multiple of the byte-size of dtype, you must specify shape.

So, just use regular Python functions to get the file size, figure out how many full elements the file contains, and pass that as `shape`.  The exception you were getting will no longer occur.  It's easy to see why if you look at the source code: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/ab49be1/numpy/core/memmap.py - the exception can only be thrown if `shape is None`.

Comment: You can get the file size using `os.stat(f).st_size`